# reduce the size of the army of particles in liquid war

Tags: liquid-war

In Liquid War each player has an army of particles. It would be cool to get the clue of the mechanisms, if you could reduce the number of particles and slow down the game to a speed, where you could watch each particle to battle.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hey, @rubo.  I've taken the last bit out of your question, because that's off-topic for Arqade.  We don't do recommendations.

Comment: OK. I didn't find any settings for that. Maybe you can modify the game source somehow? Or someone already did?